# The radical of an algebraic group is a torus

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

How to show that the radical of a reductive linear algebraic group is a torus $(\mathbb C^*)^n$?

Comment: How do you define reductive? (I define it as the radical being a torus).

Comment: the unipotent radical is trivial

Comment: Ok, so you need to show that if a connected solvable group has trivial unipotent radical, then it is a torus. For this you can use that it will be isomorphic to a group of upper triangular matrices.

Comment: Can't we assume more since the radical actually is abelian?

Comment: Sure, if you already know that it is abelian you can use that (though I don't see an obvious way to show this directly).

Comment: I thought one can use the fact that every complex reductive is a complexification of a maximal  compact (real) subgroup, which has a real (compact) torus radical.. and the complexification of this torus is $(\mathbb C^*)^n$???

Comment: Ohh, I was going more directly from the definition here (and also tried to avoid anything specific about the complex numbers, since that is unnecessary for this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard example of connected solvable group is the group of (upper) triangular non-singular matrices.
This has a nice structure theorem: semi-direct product of torus with strictly upper triangular (i.e., 1's in the diagonal)

Lie-Kolchin theorem states that connected solvable groups are closed subgroups of the above.

Now unipotent radical is trivial hypothesis combined with the above should tell you that it is a torus.

Comment: Well, at first that it is a subgroup of a torus. But since it is also connected, that makes it a torus itself.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Yes, this point needs to be added. Thanks.